# How to move only 3 rows from one tab to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this demo sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Zr1ij6KbKbL5IHrVYBNPWmWSWkntZz9amrNBInQY6c/edit?usp=sharing

What im trying to do is:

From Tab Ventas if column S have an "M" to move to the tab "V"

But I only want to move the first 3 entries containing "M" all others to stay there

Im looking for a script for this

How can I accomplish this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**Move to V**

```
function moveToV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Ventas');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('V')
  var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=3;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][18]=='M') {
      sh2.appendRow(vA[i]);
      sh1.deleteRow(i+1-d);
    }
  }
}
```